# How can I visualise two indices that are on the same scale in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, data-visualization

I have two measures of risk that are negatively correlated e.g.

```
x <- runif(30,0,1)
y <- -x + rnorm(30,0,0.1)
plot(x,y)
```

I would like to make a combined map of these risk factors but I'm not sure of how to colour code my data. I think I need two colour scales so that each quadrant on my scatterplot would have a different colour.

I've looked up [risk heat maps](https://knowledger.rbind.io/post/creating-a-risk-matrix-in-r/) but they generally range from green to red. This results in the top left and bottom right quadrants getting the same colour which is something I don't want.

Comment: What do you want to see? Something like x on x-axis, y on y-axis, and count of the co-occurrencies as value (and color)?

Comment: This is too broad for a SO question, you need to make this answerable in an objective way.

Answer (score 0):

Since your x's are always non-negative,  your points will alw3ays be in quadrant 1 or 4. This is completely determined by whether or not the y value is positive. So you can just make a simple variable to indicate the quadrant using `ifelse`.

```
x <- runif(30,0,1)
y <- -x + rnorm(30,0,0.1)

QuadCol = ifelse(y < 0, 1, 2)
plot(x,y, pch=21, bg=QuadCol)
```

[image: Points colored by quadrant]